# Why was the first Temple destroyed?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tisha-bav

Why was the first Temple destroyed?  The Talmud says it's because the people engaged in idolatry, adultery and murder. [Yoma 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.9b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
But after the 55 disastrous years of King Menashe, during which he all but stamped out the Torah and encouraged all manner of idolatry, came King Josiah, who restored the Torah and led public repentance, massive reform, and a return to observance.

But God told Josiah, through the prophetess Hulda, that He will bring disaster on their heads anyway. Why? If God did not punish them during Menashe's reign, it must have been to give them opportunities to repent. And they did. So why did God resolve to punish them anyway? Isn't repentance what God really wants?  Sure, not every single individual repented, but still, it was a huge step in the right direction.

Comment: Further complicating matters, on BT Bava Meziah 85b and  BT Nedarim 81, Rav Yehuda brings in the name of Rav that the first temple was destroyed because people neglected to recite the Birkhat HaTorah (this is usually understood to mean they studied it as a dry subject matter rather than applying it to their lives)https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.85b?lang=bi sefaria.org/Nedarim.81a?lang=bi